# Trigger email bounce flag on Lead

Tags: marketing-cloud

In Sales Cloud, there's a functionality that updates 'EmailBouncedDate' and 'EmailBouncedReason' fields when an email get bounces, and it automatically creates a warning flag on the email address field on lead. As we send most of our emails from Marketing Cloud and would like to trigger this warning on the lead when an email get bounced in Marketing Cloud through an automation.

As the above fields are not writable, how can we get access to these field or is there any workaround?